# What object do I synchronize on in Scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

In C# it's pretty straightforward:

```
class Class1{
  private static readonly object locker = new object();
  void Method1(){
    lock(locker) { .... }
  }
}
```

And I definitely should not make a synchronization on `this` because it might lead to a deadlock. Likewise, in Scala I saw examples and couldn't get the idea of what is the basic principle of synchronization and object (field) I should use to make a synchronization:

```
#1
def add(user: User) {
  // tokenizeName was measured to be the most expensive operation.
  val tokens = tokenizeName(user.name)

  tokens.foreach { term =>
    userMap.synchronized {
      add(term, user)
    }
  }
}

#2
class Person(var name: String) {
  def set(changedName: String) {
    this.synchronized {
      name = changedName
    }
  }
}

#3 and so on...
```

Would you mind making it clear for me?

Comment: while synchronizing is possible in scala, it would be more idiomatic to eliminate the need for it. E.g use immutable data structures and design programs in a way that allows for non-blocking aynchronous execution.

Comment: @rompetroll, I'm very curious about it. Can you please show me an example? But nonetheless, even using immutable data structures is just **moving the responsibility of synchronization further**, for example, to someone who will use this code with immutable state, eventually it will necessary to use it. As far as I understand, it's not possible to avoid using  `synchronized` method even when there are **only** immutable data structures. Isn't that so?

Comment: If your program doesn't fork, why would you need `synchronized`? If your sub routines are all based on immutable structures, the only place where state updates are seen is your main method. You can perfectly design large libraries without the need to introduce a single `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: @Grienders, No, it is entirely possible. If your data is *completely* immutable (with *no* exceptions; this also implies that there are no I/O operations performed), then no explicit synchronization is really needed, because no thread would be able to interfere with other thread operations in *any* way.

Comment: However, with immutable data the only way you can transfer data between threads is starting new child thread with new piece of data. This can be very inconvenient and ineffective, so you eventually just have to have mutable state. But different libraries try to abstract this state so you won't access it directly, so you still won't need `synchronized`. For example, that is what actor libraries (e.g. Akka) do. On lower level each actor has *mutable queue* of messages, but you do not access it directly, you use *immutable messages* instead. Hence, no `synchronized` in *your* code.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, there is no difference between mutable state and using synchronized. using synchronized involves using mutable state. However, I'd like not to use both  synchronized and mutable variables at all. It seems like it's not possible. How do, let's say, Haskell deal with that, it doesn't have mutability?

Comment: "In C# [...] I definitely should not make a synchronization on this because it might lead to a deadlock". So synchronizing on locker does not lead to deadlock regardless of what is in the `{....}` block? I don't know anything about C# and coming from Java I find that claim extraordinary. Do you have links/references on this? It seems to me that if the synchronized block calls other methods that go acquire other locks all bets are off.

Comment: @huynhjl - do a search on "c# lock this deadlock"

Comment: @Grienders, yes, you cannot use mutable state without `synchronized` (or its analogues, or some high-level construct which itself is based on synchronized). But I can't see your point and your problem. You say you don't want "to use both synchronized and mutable variables at all`. Well, then just don't use mutable variables, and you won't need `synchronized`, it is as simple as this.

Comment: Also, Haskell really *has* mutability. This is the type of `forkIO`, Haskell's function to start thread: `forkIO :: IO a -> IO ThreadId`. It means that it takes *IO action* and executes it in another thread. And since it is an IO action, it perfectly can use mutable state (`IORef`s, `TVar`s, `MVar`s etc.). Haskell has its own means to perform locks and synchronization. It also has more higher-level concept, called software transactional memory (btw, Clojure has it too, as well as Scala).

Comment: @Grienders, ok, I see, it's about making the lock object visible (which is the case with `this`), so some other code you don't control can lock on it. You may be able to do this with a very fine control in Scala.

Comment: @huynhjl what do you mean, how?

Comment: @Grienders, see my answer, you can synchronized on an object only visible to a single object instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Having a lock on **object** in Scala is the same as having the lock on static field/class in Java, which is basically one of 'hardest' locks. It will block operations not on instance of class, but on class itself in scope of class loader. You should think carefully when introducing locks like this. It doesn't protect you from a deadlock due to incorrect ordering of acquired locks, but instead leads to blocking threads if ones are working with different instances of a class, and may not interfere at all.
2. having a lock on 'this' or some class (not object) field (mutex) is more relaxed way of synchronization, you should use it for managing access not to class - but to particular instance of this class.
3. look at actors in [akka](http://akka.io), they rock and eliminate many of problems with synchronization.

*side-note*: making synchronization on 'this' doesn't imply deadlocks.

Comment: `making synchronization on 'this' doesn't imply deadlocks.` - in Java? In C# it might does.

Comment: I'm not sure how just making it synchronized on class instance can lead to deadlock alone. If you lock instance A in thread B, then try to lock instance C, and lock instance C in thread D and try to lock on instance A - then you're in trouble disregard of what objects A and C (static or not).

Comment: **making synchronization on 'this' doesn't imply deadlocks**. -- in Java? In C# it might do for sure

Comment: I think the words in #1 are not chosen carefully (i.e., wrong). A Scala object is analogous to Java statics, but it's just an ordinary instance under the hood, a static field something like Foo$.MODULE$.  Foo.synchronized means syncd on that instance, not on Foo$.class.

Comment: I don't know about C#, but synchronizing on `this` does not automatically introduce a risk of deadlocks in either Java or Scala. It depends on what you're doing with them. If one thread could synchronize on instance A and instance B (in that order) while another thread synchronizes on instance B and instance A, then you're in trouble.

Comment: I wonder, why no one said that synchronize is a method in Scala, likewise it's an operator in Java?

Comment: @Grienders, I guess because it doesn't matter. Scala compiler should be intelligent enough to transform calls to `synchronized` method to the same bytecode which Java compiler produces on `synchronized` statement.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, yes, it figures. However, what do you think about this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129963/what-object-do-i-syncronize-on-in-scala/17131762?noredirect=1#comment24791284_17129963

Comment: It's the same situation, locking on this will mean you are locking on a key (the class instance) that can be access by other people, also you are locking the whole instance witch can be used by an unknown amount, so it's better to avoid "this" ;)

Answer (score 19):

In Scala it's even more straightforward to get the same behavior (I'm assuming you want to lock on the contained object for some reason e.g. more fine-grained control than locking the whole instance of that class):

```
class Class1 {
  private object Locker
  def method1 { Locker.synchronized { ... } }
}
```

But you should rarely control things this way.  In particular, it won't prevent deadlocks in either C# or Scala without a lot of attention to what goes into `...`.

You should at least use the concurrency tools in `java.util.concurrent`, and you may want to look into futures or actors.

Comment: @Grienders __this is Scala__, and indeed the correct way to make a private lock, which reduces the risk of deadlocks, because `Class1` fully controls where that lock is used. If you only have one private lock, you cannot run into a deadlock. You need at least two locks for a potential deadlock.

Comment: @Grienders - That is Scala.  You said "In C# it is pretty straightforward".  I showed how to do the exact same thing in Scala even more simply.  So if you already know how to do it in C#, now you know how to do it in Scala.

Comment: @0__ - You do need at least two locks, but they can be two locks on different instances of the same class.  So even with a single private lock you have to take considerable care.

Comment: Trust me, I write Scala since years. This compiles. I take it you remove the ellipsis `...` which is a placeholder.

Comment: @Rex exactly. BTW I use `private val lock = new AnyRef`, looks a bit less pretty, but doesn't introduce the overhead of an inner class.

Comment: you're right, sorry. anyway, why do you use object here? why not use just `this.synchronized`.

Comment: @Grienders - I assumed you had a good reason to not lock on `this` in your C# example.

Comment: yes, but what about Scala example? It seems like there is nothing with locking on "this".

Comment: @Grienders - You do it the way you'd (hopefully) expect.  `def method { synchronized { ??? } }`.  You can be explicit with `this.synchronized` if you want.

Comment: I mean, is there a big difference between `Locker.synchronized` (locking on object) and just `synchronized` (locking on this)? Which one is better?

Comment: @Grienders - You may as well lock on `this` unless you want more fine-grained control (i.e. sometimes you will lock on `Locker` and sometimes on `this`, depending on what you need access to).

Comment: Might I also add queues (apart from futures/actors)? (Actors have queues but it might be easier setting up explicit queues than using actors depending on the context).

Comment: In my case, whatever comes in `...` is actually given as a run-time parameter. Is using your code this way dangerous?

Comment: @Jus12 - Depends on the contents of `...`, as I said.

Answer (score 9):

If the premise is that you want to avoid locking on `this` because another thread with third party code can lock on the same object, then Scala offers one more level of visibility `private[this]`.

```
class C {
  private[this] val lock = new Object()
  def method1(): Unit = lock.synchronized {
    println("method1")
  }
}
```

Here actually no other object other than a particular instance of `C` can access `lock`. Even other instances from the same class cannot access `lock`.