# Pros and cons of using spinlock while DB locking

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm

I have the following three variants of Scala code that take as input some method and calls it atomically. The method could have some db/read write  operations among other things. I don't know in advance what method it will be except that it terminates in < 100 millis. Pasting Scala code for brevity but imagining a Java version should be straightforward.

```
val locked = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean(false)
def usingAtoimcSleepLock[T](f: => T):T = {
  while (! locked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {Thread.sleep(10)}
  try f
  finally locked.set(false)
} 
def usingAtoimcSpinLock[T](f: => T):T = {
  while (! locked.compareAndSet(false, true)) { /* do nothing */ }
  try f
  finally locked.set(false)
} 
def usingAtoimcTimeoutLock[T](f: => T):T = {
  var ctr = 0
  while (! locked.compareAndSet(false, true)) { 
     if (ctr > 1000) throw new Exception("lock could not be opened")
     ctr = ctr + 1
     // can add Thread.sleep
  }
  try f
  finally locked.set(false)
}
```

Which of the above 3 methods is recommended? In particular is `usingAtomicSpinLock` recommended?

I feel `usingAtomicTimeoutLock` with a `Thread.sleep` is the best option. However, I also feel it could waste time due to context switching.

EDIT: I am not asking "what objects should I synchronize?". What I want to know is "how should I synchronize the objects (that I know)"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What object do I synchronize on in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129963/what-object-do-i-synchronize-on-in-scala)

Comment: Using spinlocks over critical sections that span blocking I/O operations is simply dumb, unless the programming language doesn't provide mutexes or anything of their ilk.

Comment: A spinlock is a synchronization primitive. Mutual exclusion is a form of sychronization. As you can see, the referenced question is in fact about locking.

Comment: Still I don't see how the linked question answers this. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Kaz I agree that using mutex better but won't that lead to possibility of deadlock and I need to be extra careful. Here I can simply timeout?

Comment: Spin lock is useful for typically very short operations << 10 microseconds. If this value is only every set once it might make sense but I doubt ti. For operation of above 100 microseconds you should seriously consider using conventional locking/Condition  A CAS with a sleep is possibly the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Using your own spin-lcok instead of a `synchronised` lock is probably not worthwhile because [the JVM might automatically use a spin-lock *when that is worthwhile* anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689718/what-is-adaptive-spinning-w-r-t-lock-acquisition)